# how can i declare variables via macros?

Tags: c, macros, line, declare

first of all, I'm using MS's Visual Studio and using C language.

Recently I need to declare variables with just one same statement which likes a macro.

However as you know, I can declare just one variable which have same name.

for example, this is not possible.

```
int iVar1;
int iVar1; // this is not possible.
```

so I thought about macros include **__*LINE*__** , if I can use this predefined macro, I can declare lots of variables via just one macro statement.

But it was difficult to make.

I made macro like this.

```
#define MY_LINE_VARIABLE        int g_iLine##__LINE__##Var = 0;
```

but after compile, i could get this variable named 'g_iLine_*LINE*_Var' instead of 'g_iLine123Var'

I want to know that is this possile, and how can i make it.

Furthermore, I need to use **__*FILE*__** macro if possible. but this macro might be changed with string data. so I can not be sure.

Any advice will be helpful.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can I ask what your overall goal is? There may be a better way (with or without macros) to accomplish this.

Comment: @Chris I've seen it with [static assertions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html), not much else.

Comment: @Darpangs, normally you would have a block inside the macro, e.g. `#define MACRO(x) { int temp = 0; ... }` is this not sufficient?

Comment: my goal is... pretty long story. I need to distinguish my global variables while run-time for data integrity. and i can not use data section because of packing software like themida. so I consider that sign it via couple of specific global variables which are initialized with special magic number.

Comment: Please illustrate what you want by editing the question. While editing the put an EDIT and write what you want. That way anybody who sees this question would be able to answer you.

Comment: Are you sure an array wouldn't be a better solution?

Answer (score 7):

As @Chris Lutz has rightly said that, there might be a better way  to accomplish what you want. Consider asking what you want to achieve.

But if you are just curious, this is the way to do:

```
#define var(z) int g_iLine##z##var = 0
#define decl(x) var(x)
#define MY_LINE_VARIABLE        decl(__LINE__)
MY_LINE_VARIABLE;
MY_LINE_VARIABLE;
```

Comment: thank you for your help!. I'm pretty newbie about macros. so your commnet will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

From [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/cpp_1.html#SEC11) link :

> After the preprocessor expands a macro name, the macro's definition
>   body is appended to the front of the remaining input, and the check
>   for macro calls continues. Therefore, the macro body can contain calls
>   to other macros.

So in your case :

`MY_VARIABLE_LINE` is converted to `int g_iLine__LINE__Var;`. But now `__LINE__` is not a valid token anymore and is not treated as a predefined macro.

Aditya's code works like this:

`MY_VARIABLE_LINE` is converted to `decl(__LINE__)` which is converted to `var(123)` which is converted to `int giLine123var = 0`.

Edit: This is for GNU C